# Call a private method in public method in a class

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, division

I want to overload operator/ in a class. to do it I want to define private inversion method which calculate inversion of first complex number(1/Z1) and then multiply by the second complex number.
I developed the code which give me an error

```
Exc20.cc: In function ‘ComplexNumber operator/(const ComplexNumber&, const ComplexNumber&)’:
Exc20.cc:75:31: error: ‘inversion’ was not declared in this scope
return ComplexNumber(com1 * inversion(com2));
```

and the body of the code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class ComplexNumber
{
public:
  double re;
  double im;
  ComplexNumber(double real = 0, double imag = 0): re{real}, im{imag} {};

private:
  ComplexNumber& inversion(const ComplexNumber& com);
};

ComplexNumber& ComplexNumber::inversion(const ComplexNumber& com)
{
  re =  com.re/sqrt(com.re*com.re + com.im*com.im);
  im = -com.im/sqrt(com.re*com.re + com.im*com.im);
  return *this;
}

ComplexNumber operator*(const ComplexNumber& com1,const ComplexNumber& com2)
{
  return ComplexNumber(com1.re*com2.re-com1.im*com2.im,com1.re*com2.im+com1.im*com2.re);
}

ComplexNumber operator/(const ComplexNumber& com1, const ComplexNumber& com2)
{
  return ComplexNumber(com1 * inversion(com2));
}

int main()
{
  ComplexNumber com1(3,7);
  ComplexNumber com2(4,2);
  com2.print();
  com3=com1/com2;
  com3.print();
}
```

Comment: `inversion` is a `ComplexNumber` member function. It needs to be invoked on a `ComplexNumber` object.

Comment: Consider using operators as member functions.

Comment: Something else to note: You made both real and imag default to 0. Which means you may want to mark that constructor as `explicit` or it may surprisingly create ComplexNumber objects with just an integer like `7`. Or maybe that's what you want.

Comment: There is a strong case to be made for making `inversion` a free function that returns a new `ComplexNumber` rather than turning `this` into the inverse of `com`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `inversion` function is a class member which means it has to be called on a class object. The way you have it in your code is calling it as if it was a free function or class static.

You could make it class static. Or you could change it so you can call it on an object like `com2.inversion()`

Making it private means that `operator/` cannot call it. However, if you were to put your operator functions inside your class and make them friends it would work. Like so:

```
friend ComplexNumber operator/(const ComplexNumber& com1, const ComplexNumber& com2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler cannot find `inversion` in `operator/` because `inversion` is a `ComplexNumber` member function and needs to be invoked on an instance of `ComplexNumber`. In addition it is a `private` member and cannot accessed outside `ComplexNumber` except by `ComplexNumber`'s `friend`s.

As a member function, `inversion` operates on a `ComplexNumber` instance, changing it into the inverse of the `com` parameter. Most uses of this would require the user to create a temporary `ComplexNumber` to store the inversion. Instead we can make `inversion` a free function that returns a new `ComplexNumber`.

```
ComplexNumber inversion(const ComplexNumber& com)
{
    ComplexNumber temp;
    temp.re = com.re / sqrt(com.re * com.re + com.im * com.im);
    temp.im = -com.im / sqrt(com.re * com.re + com.im * com.im);
    return temp;
}
```

This solves all of the problems of

```
ComplexNumber operator/(const ComplexNumber& com1, const ComplexNumber& com2)
{
    return ComplexNumber(com1 * inversion(com2));
}
```

Assembled example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class ComplexNumber
{
public:
    double re;
    double im;
    ComplexNumber(double real = 0, double imag = 0) : re { real }, im { imag }
    {
    }
};

ComplexNumber inversion(const ComplexNumber& com)
{
    ComplexNumber temp;
    temp.re = com.re / sqrt(com.re * com.re + com.im * com.im);
    temp.im = -com.im / sqrt(com.re * com.re + com.im * com.im);
    return temp;
}

ComplexNumber operator*(const ComplexNumber& com1, const ComplexNumber& com2)
{
    return ComplexNumber(com1.re * com2.re - com1.im * com2.im,
                         com1.re * com2.im + com1.im * com2.re);
}

ComplexNumber operator/(const ComplexNumber& com1, const ComplexNumber& com2)
{
    return com1 * inversion(com2); // operator * already makes a new ComplexNumber. No 
                                   // need to make another
}

int main()
{
    ComplexNumber com1(3, 7);
    ComplexNumber com2(4, 2);
    ComplexNumber com3 = com1 / com2;
}
```